# Most efficient way to get posts with postmeta

Tags: post-meta, sql

I need to get a bunch of posts with their metadata. Of course you can't get metadata with a standard posts query, so you generally have to do a `get_post_custom()` for each post.

I'm trying with one custom query, like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT  p.ID,
        p.post_title,
        pm1.meta_value AS first_field,
        pm2.meta_value AS second_field,
        pm3.meta_value AS third_field
    FROM    $wpdb->posts p LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm1 ON (
            pm1.post_id = p.ID  AND
            pm1.meta_key    = 'first_field_key'
        ) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm2 ON (
            pm2.post_id = p.ID  AND
            pm2.meta_key    = 'second_field_key'
        ) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm3 ON (
            pm3.post_id = p.ID  AND
            pm3.meta_key    = 'third_field_key'
        )
    WHERE   post_status = 'publish'
");
```

Seems to work. It trips up if you use any of those meta fields in a way that allows multiple meta values for it on the same post. I can't think of a join to do that.

So, question 1: Is there a join, sub-query, or whatever, to bring in multiple-value meta fields?

But question 2: Is it worth it? How many `postmeta` table joins do I add before a 2-query approach becomes preferable? I could grab all post data in one query, then grab all relevant postmeta in another, and combine the meta with the post data in one resultset in PHP. Would that end up being quicker than an single ever-more-complex SQL query, if that's even possible?

I always think, "Give as much work as possible to the database." Not sure on this one!

Comment: I'm not sure if you even want to do the joins.  the combination of get_posts() and get_post_meta() gives you the same data back.  In fact, it's less efficient using the joins since you might be retrieving data you won't use later.

Comment: Isn't post meta data cached automatically anyway?

Comment: @rxn, if I have several hundred posts coming back (they're a custom post type), surely it's quite a heavy DB load to `get_posts()`, then `get_post_meta()` for every one of those?

@MannyFleurmond, it's hard to find hard info on WP's built-in caching, but AFAIK it would cache stuff per request. The call to the server to grab this data is an AJAX call, and I don't think anything else will be grabbing stuff before it.

Comment: Actually, I'm going for multiple queries and caching the results. It turns out we not only need post meta, including fields that have multiple values, we also need data on users connected to the posts via meta fields (two sets of these), plus user meta on them. Pure SQL is definitely out of the window!

Answer (score 62):

Post meta information is automatically cached in memory for a standard `WP_Query` (and the main query), unless you specifically tell it not to do so by using the `update_post_meta_cache` parameter.

Therefore, you should not be writing your own queries for this.

How the meta caching works for normal queries:

If the `update_post_meta_cache` parameter to the `WP_Query` is not set to false, then after the posts are retrieved from the DB, then the `update_post_caches()` function will be called, which in turn calls `update_postmeta_cache()`.

The `update_postmeta_cache()` function is a wrapper for `update_meta_cache()`, and it essentially calls a simple `SELECT` with all the ID's of the posts retrieved. This will have it get all the postmeta, for all the posts in the query, and save that data in the object cache (using `wp_cache_add()`).

When you do something like `get_post_custom()`, it's checking that object cache first. So it's not making extra queries to get the post meta at this point. If you've gotten the post in a `WP_Query`, then the meta is already in memory and it gets it straight from there.

Advantages here are many times greater than making a complex query, but the greatest advantage comes from using the object cache. If you use a persistent memory caching solution like XCache or memcached or APC or something like that, and have a plugin that can tie your object cache to it (W3 Total Cache, for example), then your whole object cache is stored in fast memory already. In which case, there's *zero* queries necessary to retrieve your data; it's already in memory. Persistent object caching is awesome in many respects.

In other words, your query is probably loads and loads slower than using a proper query and a simple persistent memory solution. Use the normal `WP_Query`. Save yourself some effort.

**Additional:** `update_meta_cache()` is smart, BTW. It won't retrieve meta information for posts that already have their meta information cached. It doesn't get the same meta twice, basically. Super efficient.

**Additional additional:** "Give as much work as possible to the database."... No, this is the web. Different rules apply. In general, you always want to give as *little* work as possible to the database, if it's feasible. Databases are slow or poorly configured (if you didn't configure it specifically, you can bet good money that this is true). Often they are shared among many sites, and overloaded to some degree. Usually you have more web servers than databases. In general, you want to just get the data you want out of the DB as fast and simply as possible, then do the sorting out of it using the web-server-side code. As a general principle, of course, different cases are all different.

Answer (score 44):

I would recommend a pivot query. Using your example:

```
SELECT  p.ID,   
        p.post_title, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'first_field' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as first_field,
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'second_field' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as second_field,
        MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'third_field' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as third_field,

 FROM    wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID)                      
GROUP BY
   p.ID,p.post_title
```

Comment: This answer should be marked correct.

Comment: If you are looking for a database query this is the correct answer

Comment: This query reduced my time when I was using WP_Query from ~25 secs to ~3 secs. My requirement was to fire this only once so no caching was needed.

Comment: What en elegant query. Left joins didn't work in my case because they're pretty slow … this helped me exporting thousands of posts in under a second. +1

Answer (score 12):

I've come across a case where I want also want to quickly retrieve lots of posts with their associated meta information.  I need to retrieve O(2000) posts.

I tried it using Otto's suggestion - running WP_Query::query for all posts, and then looping through and running get_post_custom for each post.  **This took, on average, about 3 seconds to complete**.

I then tried Ethan's pivot query (though I didn't like having to manually ask for each meta_key I was interested in).  I still had to loop through all retrieved posts to unserialize the meta_value.  **This took, on average, about 1.3 seconds to complete**.

I then tried using the GROUP_CONCAT function, and found the best result.  Here's the code:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000'); // necessary to get more than 1024 characters in the GROUP_CONCAT columns below
$query = "
    SELECT p.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_key ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR '||') as meta_keys, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(pm.meta_value ORDER BY pm.meta_key DESC SEPARATOR '||') as meta_values 
    FROM $wpdb->posts p 
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.ID 
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and p.post_status = 'publish' 
    GROUP BY p.ID
";

$products = $wpdb->get_results($query);

// massages the products to have a member ->meta with the unserialized values as expected
function massage($a){
    $a->meta = array_combine(explode('||',$a->meta_keys),array_map('maybe_unserialize',explode('||',$a->meta_values)));
    unset($a->meta_keys);
    unset($a->meta_values);
    return $a;
}

$products = array_map('massage',$products);
```

**This took on average 0.7 seconds**.  That's about a quarter of the time of the WP get_post_custom() solution and about half of the pivot query solution.

Maybe this will be of interest to someone.

Comment: I would be interested in what results you get with a persistent object cache solution. The object cache will sometimes be slower for the base case, depending on your database and configuration, but real world results with a majority of hosts will give widely varying results. Memory based caching is ridiculously fast.

Comment: Hey @Otto. Regardless of which method I use to get the data, I definitely want to cache the result.  I've tried using the transient API to do it, but I'm hitting memory problems.  The serialized string for my 2000 objects clocks at ~8M and set_transient() fails (memory exhausted).  Also, have to change the max_allowed_packet MySQL setting.  I'll look into caching it to file, but I'm not sure yet of the the performance there.  Is there a way to cache to memory that persists across requests?

Comment: Yes, if you have a persistent memory cache (XCache, memcached, APC, etc), and use an object caching plugin (W3 Total Cache supports many types of memory caches), then it stores all the object cache in memory, giving you a many-fold speedup of pretty much everything.

Comment: I am returning 6000 items to use in a backbone/underscore js filtering scheme. This took a 6s custom query that I couldn't even run as a WP_Query because it timed out, and made it a 2s query. Although the array_map slows it back down quite a bit...

Comment: Is there any support for building high performance support for returning all meta data within a WP_Query?

Comment: I was working on a similar solution, shame SQL doesn't seem to be able to return group arrays or objects. You could try nested select, but from my earlier experience with SQL, they seem to slow the request down way to much.

Answer (score 6):

I found myself in a situation that I needed to do this task to ultimately create a CSV document from, I ended up working directly with mysql to do this. My code joins the post and meta tables to retrieve woocommerce pricing information, the previously posted solution required that I use table aliases in the sql to work properly.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_regular_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as regular_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sale_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sale_price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku
    FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID)                 
    WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title
```

Do be warned though, woocommerce created 300K+ rows in my meta table, so it was very large, and therefore very slow.

Comment: for those that are trying to squeeze more performance out of the postmeta query, this also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/392967/27357

Answer (score 1):

## NO SQL VERSION:

Get all posts and all of their meta values (metas) with no SQL:

Let's say you have a list of post IDs stored as an array of IDs, something like

```
$post_ids_list = [584, 21, 1, 4, ...];
```

Now getting all posts and all metas in 1 query is not possible without using at least a bit of SQL,
so we must do 2 queries (still just 2):

### 1. Get all the posts ( using [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) )

```php
$request = new WP Query([
  'post__in' => $post_ids_list,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, //if you want to ignore the "stickiness"
]);
```

(Don't forget to call [`wp_reset_postdata();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) if you are doing a ["loop"](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#standard-loop) afterwards ;) )

### 2. Update meta cache

```php
//don't be confused here: "post" means content type (post X user X ...), NOT post type ;)
update_meta_cache('post', $post_ids_list);
```

To get the meta data just use the standard [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) which, as @Otto pointed out:
[***looks into cache first :)***](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_meta_cache/#source)

**Note:** *If you don't actually need other data from the posts (like title, content, ... ) **you can do just 2.** :-)*

Answer (score 0):

using the solution form trevor and modifying it to work with nested SQL.
This is not tested.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
    SELECT p.*, (select pm.* From $wpdb->postmeta AS pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID)
    FROM $wpdb->posts p 
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and p.post_status = 'publish' 
";
$products = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the multiple value meta fields problem as well. The problem is with WordPress itself. Look in wp-includes/meta.php. Look for this line:

```
$where[$k] = ' (' . $where[$k] . $wpdb->prepare( "CAST($alias.meta_value AS {$meta_type}) {$meta_compare} {$meta_compare_string})", $meta_value );
```

The problem is with the CAST statement. In a query for meta values, the $meta_type variable is set to CHAR. I don't know the details on how CASTing the value to CHAR affects the serialized string, but to fix it, you can remove the cast so the SQL looks like this:

```
$where[$k] = ' (' . $where[$k] . $wpdb->prepare( "$alias.meta_value {$meta_compare} {$meta_compare_string})", $meta_value );
```

Now, even though that works, you're mucking with the WordPress internals, so other things might break, and it's not a permanent fix, assuming you'll need to upgrade WordPress.

The way I've fixed it is to copy the SQL generated by WordPress for the meta query I want and then write some PHP to tack on extra AND statements for the meta_values I'm looking for and use $wpdb->get_results($sql) for the final output. Hacky, but it works.

Comment: I've not tried it, but leveraging the `get_meta_sql` filter that follows this line would of course be preferable to hacking core code.