# post loop causes wp_users and wp_usermeta DB queries for each users

Tags: loop, query

Continuing my [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203875): My post loop produces 2 queries per post:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '53'
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/BT/search.php'), the_post, WP_Query->the_post, WP_Query->setup_postdata, get_userdata, get_user_by, WP_User::get_data_by #20 (0.1ms)
SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (53) ORDER BY umeta_id ASC
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/BT/search.php'), the_post, WP_Query->the_post, WP_Query->setup_postdata, get_userdata, get_user_by, WP_User->init, WP_User->for_blog, WP_User->_init_caps, get_user_meta, get_metadata, update_meta_cache #21 (0.2ms)
```

This happens even after I've narrowed the template code down to a simple loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo $post->ID . "<br />";
    endwhile;
endif;
```

- Is this expected?
- Isn't Wordpress supposed to get all user data in a
  single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst WordPress has gotten pretty good at db caching for loops (thumbnails, post meta, terms), it does *not* pre-emptively cache users (authors).

So if you have 5 different authors across all the posts in your loop, that's 10 queries (1 for the user object, 1 for the user's meta cache stash). It's thanks to `WP_Query::setup_postdata()` (which is called by `the_post()`) - this line:

```
$authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
```

If the post author is already in the cache, no db hit, which is why you could have 100's of posts in your loop from 5 authors and you'd still only end up with 10 additional queries.

To pre-emptively cache all users in the loop and only ever have 2 queries, no matter how many different authors:

```
function wpse_203912_the_posts( $posts, $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() ) { // Remove this condition if you want to cache users whenever anywhere queries posts
        $user_ids = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'post_author' );
        cache_users( $user_ids );
    }

    return $posts;
}

add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpse_203912_the_posts', 10, 2 );
```

The great thing about `cache_users()` is that it will only hit the db for uncached users, so it's safe to repeatedly call it without worrying if you've already cached the user.

Comment: Works like a charm! My users generally only have 1 post each, so I ended up with lots of user-related queries.