# Is there a way getting post fields using `transition_post_status`

Tags: posts, post-meta, wp-mail, post-status

First I tried fetching post_meta data, and latest, I tried fetching `get_post_field()` inside a `transition_post_status` hooked function, like:

```
<?php
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'yes_send_email_notification', 10, 3 );
function yes_send_email_notification( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if( 'mycpt' === $post->post_type && 'new' === $old_status && 'pending' === $new_status ) :
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        /**
         * Generate Dynamic values
         */
        $post_view_link   = get_permalink( $post_id );

        $message = "My custom message<br>";
        $message .= "Link: ". esc_url( $post_view_link );

        //headers are duely passed
        //$headers = ...

        wp_mail( 'someone@example.com', 'New MyCPT submitted', $message, $headers );

    endif;
}
```

The email is working fine. Now I tried including `post_content`, `post_title` (and if possible, `post_meta` data) into the email content, inside the function, but unfortunately, I can't get any of 'em.

```
$post_id        = $post->ID;
$post_view_link = get_permalink( $post_id );
$post_title     = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post, 'display' );
$post_content   = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post, 'display' );
$post_excerpt   = wp_trim_words( $post_content, 70, null );
```

But I'm failing. `$post_title` and `$post_excerpt` aren't getting populated. (The same happened for `post_meta` fields)

How can I get `post_fields` (and if possible `post_meta` fields too) inside a `transition_post_status` hooked function?

Comment: Just guessing, but could it be that the function `get_post_field` is not available at this point and you have to access the datastructure directly, like you do with the ID?

Comment: _you have to access the datastructure directly, like you do with the ID_ - You mean a custom `$wpdb` query?

Comment: No, just `$post->post_title` and `post->post_content`

Comment: @cjbj I found `$post->post_content` is working fine, but unfortunately the `$post->post_title` isn't working. I guess the `$post` object is not complete. :(

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump` on `$post`?

Comment: @cjbj it's the answer. I'm afraid, it's my fault, just forgot to concatenate string. Please provide this as an answer, and it'd be plus, and more helpful for anybody, if you can provide a way so that `post_meta` can be fetched inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `get_post_field` wouldn't work in this situation, but if you can access `$post->ID`, you should also be able to get `$post->post_title` and `$post->post_content` (and even `$post->post_excerpt` if it's there).

The [$post object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post) includes the standard metadata, like author and publication date. Any metadata in the `wp_postmeta` table in the database can only be found with `$post->ID`, with which you should be able to get your metadata using [`get_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/). Failing that you can always [run a query on the database directly](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). Since plugins have quite some freedom in structuring their metadata it's not possible in general to say how to structure this query. Also: [read Otto's note](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/most-efficient-way-to-get-posts-with-postmeta) on this.