# Doubts about the use of metadata and how this can affect performance on Wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta

I'm working on a project with some metadata inside loops like this:

```
while( $query->have_post() ):
    the_post();
    get_post_meta( postID, postMetakey, ... );
endwhile;
```

I'm using `get_post_meta`, i was wondering if i use `get_post_meta()` i'm making a new query to the database? So I'm increasing the processing time?

if i use `get_meta()` all the data is there, already loaded in the $query variable, but I can't use this `get_meta()` for specific data, so i need to use the `get_post_meta();`

I would like to know if from a performance point of view, does it make sense to extend the functionality of the `WP_Query` class to return an associative array with the posts metadata?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [Most efficient way to get posts with postmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/38530/4771)

Comment: Don't be afraid to retrieve the metadata directly from the database, it doesn't have such an impact. But however, meta queries can some times be breath taking.

Comment: get_post_meta is a wrapper for get_metadata which checks the cache first. If no cache, then another function is called to create the cache.