# How to solve slow WordPress site caused by attachment_metadata

Tags: database, post-meta, mysql, performance, optimization

My WordPress sites starting to become slower by time, after two years they become very slow. I tried many things, such as:

- improved my DB,
- used cache plugins (WP Rocket and W3 Total Cache) which both are
  great, rocket is a little better but you have to pay for it,
- checked effects of analytics on my site (deactivating slimstat
  analytics improved my response time by 20%),
- handling heart beat (WP Rocket has a way to control heart beat).

Finally I checked core tables of WordPress (`wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`) the main reason that my WordPress site is slow is because of the `wp_postmeta`, and unfortunately WooCommerce save its meta in the `wp_postmeta` which affects response time drastically.

All of these aside, there is one more thing that has strong effect on the speed, and that is the length of `_wp_attachment_metadata` which for my site is more than 1024 characters.

How could I optimize this (`_wp_attachment_metadata`) metadata without losing all the image-sizes that I need?

Finally, if I change the type of `meta_value` of `wp_postmeta` from `longtext` to `varchar(2024)` (which I assume all plugins produce meta data with less characters) and then index it. Would it make any problem with core of WordPress?

Comment: How many rows are there in `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`? Have you done any profiling to check, which queries are slow?

Comment: there are over 40000 posts and about half million postmeta, yes I checked all queries,(using https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ - The query Monitor Plugin) and I optimized all possible queries. and the only thing that I can't do anything about is, _wp_attachment_metadata, but on a localhost (test environment) I did this query: "DELET FROM wp_postmeta where char_length(meta_value)>2024" and it deleted about 800 rows, yet improved my response time very effectively. That's why I'm looking for a way to reduce the size of meta_value of _wp_attachment_metadata

Comment: Are these 40,000 unique posts, or do you have a lot of post revisions? If revisions are enabled, just disabling them or removing the current revisions will save a lot of space.

Comment: These are unique posts

Comment: @ArashRabiee have you find solution for this since then? If so, would you be kind to answer your own question here? I'm interested in your findings. Best wishes, W

Comment: @ViktorBorítás Hi, I added an answer below but most effective one for me was to change my hosting provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the following to improve a little bit better performance,

1. limited revision to 3 by `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3);`  in wp_config.php
2. moved to another host which supported Light Speed Cache, which has a little better performance than my previous caching solution
3. updated woocommerce to version 4+
4. Increased wordPress memory limit to 512 `define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘256M’);` in wp_config.php or asking your hosting provider
5. removed analytics plugins from my site and use the option which my hosting provide for me
6. Using a CDN for images and using webp format
7. I used WPML for translating, so I cleaned the history from plugin setting, and afterward I removed all data from `WP_PREFIX_icl_strings` and only translated the required plugins, it has huge affect on my site; however, I had to check and re-translate most pages of my site (not post, only pages, archives etc)
8. Using [database clean up plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-database-cleaner/), TAKE A BACK UP BEFORE USING THIS,
9. Finally I used [POD](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) plugin and created some custom post_type which do not uses wordpress default tables, but this one is a little tricky and not recommended

Comment: Salam Arash jaan, Turning off the post revisions is really tricky. Also html caching and detecting the ATF objects is really helpfull. Are you a WordPress developeror or just a WP fan? do you have a official website or any contact points?

Answer (score 2):

Rick James and I have created the (free, GPL) [Index WP MySQL for Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) plugin. It addresses some of the performance problems with wp_postmeta by adding database indexes suitable for that table's use cases. I use it myself on a Woo site with several thousand products. (It works on users, terms, options, and comments too.)

If you'd prefer not to use a plugin, you can do the same work with phpmyadmin or some similar tool. Here's the SQL Data Definition Language the plugin uses to adjust wp_postmeta.

Before you do this make sure...

- you're using MySQL InnoDB tables
- MySQL/MariaDB 5.7+
- you have a backup

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD UNIQUE KEY meta_id (meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY (post_id, meta_key, meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP KEY post_id;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP KEY meta_key;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key, post_id);
```

These adjusted / added database keys match the common query patterns from WP core and Woo.

Comment: For me, this worked great, as the plugins I'm using created a lot of meta content, that meant millions of rows being created.  This made the job of querying the postmeta table a lot faster.  I'd recommend that this gets included in core :)

Comment: Thanks for the positive report. As for including the plugin's functionality in core, it uses some arcane features of MySql but only in the newer versions of the DBMS where they're available. Some big hosting providers (hi, Godaddy) still use the obsolete older versions. And core has to support everything.

Comment: I just rejected an edit to this answer of mine. Somebody suggested using `meta_key(60)` as a [prefix key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes). That's not necessary with InnoDB dynamic rows, and it harms performance. In the WordPress standard keys they use `meta_key(191)` due to the limitations of MyISAM indexes. [Please read this](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/wordpresss-prefix-keys/) for an in-depth explanation.